# How to get media info precisely in flutter

Tags: flutter, media

I have sensitive software operations to perform some mathematical operations depending on media info .

all what i need in order to do my job is video-image width and height.

i find my self in confutation situation . i tried to use many ways to get media info but they all give inverted values , for example

using `Ffmpeg` plugin  : it give video width say 750 and height 2080 , when i use other way like

```
 File fileCreated = File(backgroundImage);
    final image = await decodeImageFromList(await fileCreated.readAsBytes());
    log.log('image width ${image.width}');
    log.log('image width ${image.height}');
```

outPut width 2080and height 750 .. it inverted values . :|

other way

```
final info = await VideoCompress.getMediaInfo(videopath);
output w 750 h2080 !! // sometimes give inverted values compare of Gallery device
```

note : if i use the Gallery storage info manually it always make my task done correctly

i need A unified way to bring the right information to everyone

Comment: You are already getting the media info. The real question is should be which one is consistent and correct for your usage. It may be inverted by design, may depend on the use case, etc. Use any of these way that provides consistent result and adapt it to your use case.

Comment: my use case is always needs w/h  not h/w , however several methods provide the width as height and height as width , How could i determine which us actual width  of these methods .. this is weird , i think it depends on media orientation